# How to kill a running google AUTOML training job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl

I have launched a google AutoML job on google cloud platform on some data, I have later realised I have made a mistake in the data. How do I stop the running training model job?  not very intuitive...

EDIT:
here is a picture of my screen (It is a regression model)
[image]

Comment: Which specific AutoML product (e.g NL, Vision, Translation, etc...)? I believe not all has the cancel button after clicking the Train model under the Train tab.

Answer (score 0):

I talked to the PM, and we don't have it across all flavors of AutoML. That's why I was seeing it (I was looking in Vision). They're actively working on it. No word on when they'll have it yet, but it's a known thing.

Old Answer: I may have a different screen than you since I'm internal here, but when you hit the "train" button, it should have a status screen on the train tab that just says "Training your model" with a big cancel button? Could you post a screenshot of what you see once you hit "train"?